# Can I (re)move Microsoft Help files?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007, disk-space, visual-studio-2008, user-profiles

I have limited profile space and it seems that Visual Studio and Office insist on filling it up with "Microsoft Help" files. The are located in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft Help (I'm on Windows 7 64-bit if that's relevant).

Does anyone know what these do? Can I move this folder outside my profile folder? If not, is it safe to delete the (largest) files? Is there any way to influence how these files are created (like when, where, how many, what size, etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have MSDN help documentation installed (these are very large) use Control Panel Add/Remove to uninstall them. That location hardly takes any space on my PC, how much space does it take on your side?